# Sparkling little objects in my Colaboratory notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

Just today, when writing some Python and OPENAI code in a Collaboratory notebook, all of a sudden a "particle effect" started, and for each character I typed lots of small particles would pop from the character. After some time after that the word "COMBO:" appeared in the bottom right of the screen, followed by a integer increasing number. Stopping typing,
the word floats upward. Tried Windows anti-virus, no use.  Occurs in many browsers.

Comment: its a "cool" thing that jupyter does called CodeMirror Sublime Text that has a power mode. you can disable it by: 

1. Click on Tools in the menu bar.
2. Click on Settings or Preferences.
3. Look for an option related to Editor Key Map or Editor Key Bindings.
4. Set the option back to Default or null.

Comment: Did not work. But I guess I found out.

Answer (score 2):

### It seams it is a joke from Google Colab.
I noticed it occurs depending on the "Power Level".

### Settings
Miscellaneous >
Power level >
No power  (does not happen)
Some power (happens)
Many power (happens stronger)

Looking for "Power Level in Colaboratory" I found the explanations that it is an "April Fool" joke, with no effects besides the sparkles an "Combos"...

https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1112708634905964545